# Что лучше использовать в sql in или =?

Tags: mysql, sql

В чем разница что лучше использовать?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1
```

Comment: Наиболее детально вам ответит explain. Но синтаксис с in выглядит несколько уродливо.

Разницы скорее всего не будет.

Comment: смысл первого использовать тогда аргументов несколько.

Comment: Согласен с **KoVadim**, что истина в последней инстанции - это актуальный план выполнения запроса. Так, когда `id` - первичный ключ таблицы, оба запроса дают абсолютно идентичный план запроса в MS SQL Server. Для других SQL-серверов надо выяснять отдельно, но скорей всего разницы не будет. И да, первый вариант синтаксиса годится, когда нужно искать строки по нескольким значениям ключа, а второй вариант - когда нужно отобрать из БД строго одну строку по одному конкретному значению ключа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если сравнивать только два ваших варианта, то разница только в удобстве написания. В общем случае используйте '=' если надо сравнить с одним значением и 'IN' если с множеством. С 'IN' можно использовать подзапросы. Например:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id_n FROM table2)
```

Comment: А производительность у них одинаковая?

Comment: По производительности хорошо ответил **velial**.